# Bootstrap center floated divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, centering

I'm trying to center a block of floated divs. I want that divs are always centered.

I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6qev/1/

This is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="works">
        <div class="row text-center" style="background-color:#015891; margin-bottom:10px; color:white; padding:10px;">WORKS</div>
        <div id="boxWrap">
            <div class="view"></div>
            <div class="view"></div>
            <div class="view"></div>
            <div class="view"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.view {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 0 15px 15px auto;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative; 
   background:black;
}

#boxWrap {
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks,
Francesco

Comment: You could use `display: inline-block` declaration instead of floating the boxes. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/b6qev/4/ [Then `text-align:center;` of the parent will do the trick!]

Comment: Yeah! This is the right way!

Answer (score 2):

Your fiddle doesn't include your code, but

#### [I updated it here](http://jsfiddle.net/b6qev/9/)

Change your `.view` class to the following (remove `float: left;`, `position:relative` and add `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: auto`:

```
.view {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   margin-left: auto; //add this
   margin-right: auto; //add this
   overflow: hidden;
   background:black;  
}
```

Comment: Would'nt  margin-right: auto;  be overridden with margin: 0 15px 15px auto; it should be margin: 0 auto 15px

Comment: Hi Dan, thx for your response. I've already updated my fiddle. I don't want to eliminate the float rule. If you see my updated fiddle (using 4 box now), applying your trick the box are centered but not floated. My target is to have the container always centered and the box inside floated if resolution of viewport allows the visualization.

Comment: @Pav Yeah, it was out of order.  Another option is to delete the `margin: 0 15px 15px auto;` and add `margin-top:15px;`, `margin-bottom:15px;`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative using `display:table` and `clear:float` like this:

**CSS**

```
.view {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;  
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative; 
   background:black;
   display:table-cell;
}

#boxWrap {
   margin:0 auto;
   display:table;
}

.view:nth-child(2n+1){
   clear: left;
   margin: 0 15px 15px auto;
}
```

Also apply margin only on first one.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6qev/31/)